# If $A$ is right-continuous and of bounded variation and $f$ is integrable, what is the variation of $t\mapsto\int_{(0,\:t]}f\:{\rm d}A$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Let

- $T>0$
- $I:=(0,T]$
- $A:\overline I\to\mathbb R$ be right-continuous and of bounded variation
- $f:I\to\mathbb R$ be Borel measurable with $$\int|f|\:{\rm d}|A|<\infty\tag1$$ and $$g(t):=\int_{(0,\:t]}f\:{\rm d}A\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\overline I$$

Let $(\mu^+,\mu^-)$ denote the Jordan decomposition of ${\rm d}A$ and $$f^\pm:=\max(\pm f,0)\;.$$ Then, $$g(t)=\underbrace{\left(\int_{(0,\:t]}f^+\:{\rm d}\mu^++\int_{(0,\:t]}f^-\:{\rm d}\mu^-\right)}_{=:\:g^+(t)}-\underbrace{\left(\int_{(0,\:t]}f^+\:{\rm d}\mu^-+\int_{(0,\:t]}f^-\:{\rm d}\mu^+\right)}_{=:\:g^-(t)}\tag2$$ for all $t\in\overline I$. Since $g^\pm$ is nondecreasing, we see that $g$ is of bounded variation. By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, we also obtain right-continuity of $g$.

> Now, we know that $g$ is of bounded variation. But are we able to write down the variation function of $g$ in an explicit form?

Comment: Yes: change the minus sign in the middle of the right side of (2) into a plus sign.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I'm not sure, if I understand what you're meaning. The minus sign in $(2)$ is correct. Otherwise the equation would be wrong. Or do you mean that the total variation function is $g^++g^-$?

Comment: I meant the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when $\nu$ is a signed measure with Jordan decomposition $(\nu^+,\nu^-)$, the variation function of $t\mapsto \nu((0,t])$ is $t\mapsto |\nu|((0,t])$  where $|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^-$. Not coincidentally,  $|\nu|$ called the  *variation* of $\nu$.

The reason is that the Jordan decomposition of the BV function obtained by integrating a measure corresponds to the Jordan decomposition of that measure, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable) notes.

In your case $\nu= f\mu$, so $\nu^+ = f^+\mu^++f^-\mu^-$ and $\nu^- = f^-\mu^++f^-\mu^+$, hence $|\nu| = |f| |\mu|$. In other words, the variation function is
$$t\mapsto \int_{(0,t]} |f|\:{\rm d}|A|$$
which is precisely the quantity you assumed finite.