# Proof that if $g$ is of bounded variation and $|f|\le M$ then $\left|\int_{[a,b]} f \ dg \right|\le MT$.

Tags: measure-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions, total-variation

Suppose that $g:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is a function of bounded variation, and $f$ is Borel measurable with $|f|\le M$ on $[a,b]$.  Define $g^+,g^-$ to be the Jordan decomposition so that these are increasing functions and $g=g^+-g^-$.  Let $\nu^+$ be the measure such that $g^+$ is the CDF of $\nu^+$, and likewise for $\nu^-$.  Take $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$, and define $\int_E f \ dg = \int_E f \ d\nu^+-\int_E f \ d\nu^-$.

I am trying to prove that $\left|\int_{[a,b]}f\ dg\right| \le MT$ where $T$ is the total variation of $g$.

I am primarily struggling to identify what $T$ is, as related to the measures.  It makes some amount of intuitive sense to think that $T=|\nu|[a,b]$ where $|v|=\nu^++\nu^-$, however I am not able to make this connection.  I know that

$$ \nu^+[a,x] = g^+(x)-g^+(a) $$
$$ \nu^-[a,x] = g^-(x)-g^-(a) $$

so $|\nu|[a,b]$ is

$$ \nu^+[a,b]+\nu^-[a,b] = g^+(b)-g^+(a) + g^-(b)-g^-(a)$$

I also have that $g^+(x) = g(x)+TV(g,[a,x])$ and $g^-(x) = TV(g,[a,x])$, and so $g^+(b) = g(b)-T$ and $g^+(a) = g(a)$ and so on.  But plugging this into the result above doesn't seem to reach the desired conclusion, since it becomes

$$ g(b)-T-g(a)+(0-T) = g(b)-g(a)-2T $$

I tried to parse this answer: [If $A$ is right-continuous and of bounded variation and $f$ is integrable, what is the variation of $t\mapsto\int_{(0,\:t]}f\:{\rm d}A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504832/if-a-is-right-continuous-and-of-bounded-variation-and-f-is-integrable-what)

However, I'm not sure what $f\mu$ means here.  I might assume that it is the measure such that $f$ is the CDF of $f\mu$, but then I don't understand why $(f\mu)^+ = f^+\mu^+$ and in general I'm not familiar with any theorems about generally manipulating an object like $f\mu$ assuming I've correctly identified what it is.

Comment: Suffices to prove $\int_{[a, b]} |dg| \le T$. Now I refer you to the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Formal_definition